# Combinatorics: variable accessed by two threads

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic, combinatorics

Threads A and B have concurrent access to a single variable. Each thread performs a sequence of accesses on the variable (reads and writes). Each thread stores the results from its reads into an array. The outcome of the session is defined by the two arrays.

The accesses performed by a given thread may not be re-ordered. However, accesses from the two threads may be interleaved, so the outcome will depend on this interleaving. **How can we efficiently calculate the number of possible outcomes, given the two access sequences**? Assume all writes produce distinct values.

```
    Example access sequences:
        Thread A: [write(71), read()]
        Thread B: [read(), write(72), write(73), read()]

    Example interleaving:
        [a_write(71), b_read(), b_write(72), a_read(), b_write(73), b_read()]

    Example outcome:
        a_results = [72]
        b_results = [71, 73]
```

P.s. This is not homework, it's just a problem I conceived myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like something that could be solved with dynamic programming.

I would suggest looking for a way of solving the subproblem:

> How many distinct outcomes are there given that we have done x accesses from thread 1, y accesses from thread 2, and the last access was a write that was done by thread z (either 1 or 2).

The DP array will be 3 dimensional: DP[x][y][z].

There will be a total of 2 * (number of accesses in thread 1) * (number of accesses in thread 2) slots to be calculated in the DP.

To populate each entry in the array you will need to sum several previous entries of the array so I suspect the overall complexity will be around O(n^3) where n is the number of accesses.

Comment: Thanks, I think I have a solution. What was the intuition that led you to select "which thread wrote last" as an additional DP dimension?

Comment: Just that we need this piece of information to precisely identify the current state of the variable being written to.